# android 10 device crash only on oppo devices

Tags: android, crash, native

a native crash on in android device 10, oppo. does anyone knows this bugs.

```
    SIGABRT

1 #00 pc 0002dcbe /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+165) [armeabi-v8]
2 #01 pc 00001ac1 /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+176) [armeabi-v8]
3 #02 pc 000087eb /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::MediaBuffer::set_range(unsigned int, unsigned int)+74) [armeabi-v8]
4 #03 pc 0000f3b9 /system/lib/libmedia.so [armeabi-v8]
5 #04 pc 0005cf9d /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::NuMediaExtractor::fetchTrackSamples(android::NuMediaExtractor::TrackInfo*, long long, android::MediaTrack::ReadOptions::SeekMode)+156) [armeabi-v8]
6 #05 pc 0005d6e7 /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::NuMediaExtractor::readSampleData(android::sp<android::ABuffer> const&)+90) [armeabi-v8]
7 #06 pc 000130db /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaExtractor::readSampleData(_jobject*, unsigned int, unsigned int*)+230) [armeabi-v8]
8 #07 pc 00013793 /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so [armeabi-v8]
9 #08 pc 000084a9 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (oatdata+29865) [armeabi]
10 java:
```